# solr query "msg": "undefined field text", "code": 400

Tags: solr

when i run the below query i am getting results

/select?q=*:*&fq=%28category_name:*Business*%20OR%20job_name:*abcdefgh*%29&debugQuery=true

but When run the below query 
select?q=*:*&fq=%28category_name:*Business%20dev*%20OR%20job_name:*abcdefgh*%29&debugQuery=true

results are not coming and it shows the following error

"msg": "undefined field text",
"code": 400

the only difference between the two queries is 
in the first query there is no space in the category_name key
but in the second query there is space in it .

i think it causes an issue. please post your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

When there is no field name present, the default search field is used. By default, this is `_text_` or `text`. In your query:

```
category_name:Business dev
```

.. this is NOT parsed as "search for the value `Business dev` in `category_name`", but it's parsed as "search for the value `Business` in `category_name` and `dev` in the default search field (which seems to be `text` in your case).

You fix this by properly escaping the space:

```
category_name:Business\ dev
```

.. or by using a phrase query:

```
category_name:"Business dev"
```

The [special characters that needs escaping (as they have specific meaning in a query) is](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters):

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
```

.. as well as whitespace. This should be handled automagically by your Solr library.